# How to clear a TextInput with a Button

Tags: python, kivy

I am currently working on a mental health app and I have come across a problem. I need a TextInput to be cleared whenever I hit a certain button but I am not sure exactly how to do so.

For reference this is the TextInput:

```
TextInput:
        id: text
        font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 15**4
        multiline: False
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.1 , "top":0.8}
        size_hint: 0.8, 0.7
```

And the Button that will trigger it:

```
Button:
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.0, "y": 0.95}
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.05
        text: 'Enter'
        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        on_press: text.delete_selection()
```

The Python code for this section is:

```
class Screen_One(Screen):
    text = ObjectProperty(None)

    def delete_selection(self, from_undo=False):
        if not self._selection:
            return ("")
```

As you can see, I attempted to try something but it still shows no effect and it won't clear the textinput.

Can someone please help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`text.text = ""` in your python code will do it. You can create a function like `onclick`, and if you are in an overall class, you can call `self.text.text = ""`. This resets the text of the TextInput.

Comment: I'm not familiar with onclick functions so how exactly would I present it in my python and kivy file?

Comment: Update: I figured it out. Thank you!